# How can I record video with FFMPEG in ISO BMFF format ready for Media Source Extensions?

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg, media-source

I'm trying to record video using ffmpeg and then play it back on a player using MSE. Here's the script I'm using:

```
 ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -level:v 13 -g 250 -r 25 -keyint_min 250 -strict experimental -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -b:a 96k sintel.mp4
```

This works except for the fact that there is an mfra box at the end of the video file, which I believe is not supported by MSE. How can I remove this mfra box?

Answer (score 8):

Change your movflags to:

```
-movflags empty_moov+default_base_moof
```

and if you want it to also work on Chrome, use:

```
-movflags empty_moov+default_base_moof+frag_keyframe
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Can you please explain why it works?

Comment: look here: http://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/isobmff-byte-stream-format.html at the section that starts with: A Movie Fragment Box uses movie-fragment relative addressing.....

Comment: Does not work, because the resulting MP4 does not have a duration (d = 0), this is basically useless for MSE. FFMPEG is not able to do correct MP4 fragmentation.

Comment: @Kr0e That's incorrect. MSE does not require MP4 with duration, so ffmpeg is able to do it. I was able to do it myself.

Comment: @galbarm The problem is with timestampOffset. If you have more than one buffer, then you can not do it, because SourceBuffer.buffered has no entry. So, you are right. One buffer works, multiple subsequent buffers do not work. (IMHO)

Comment: @Kr0e - To clarify - it does work if you set the SourceBuffer.timestampOffset yourself. I was able to buffer multiple files together and have them play seamlessly. You'll need to calculate the durations of each segment yourself in order to set the offset.

Comment: @AndyHin Hey, I think the problem arises when you lost one or more packets, the subsequent packet will not fit into the media source, but after further studies I dont think this is related to media source or ffmpeg. A disrupted mp4 stream has to be fixed manually, which I'm doing now and it works. So inspecting the mp4 internal timestamps and remembering _your_ actual duration so new packets (even if there were lost packets in between) can be adjusted nicely. So yes: You were right if the stream generated by ffmpeg is continously consumed. My bad.

Comment: @AndyHin, thanks for great information. 
how do you calculate the duration of each segment?
and when do you call to timestampOffset? I got error after calling this every time, before and after the append..

Comment: Thank you from 2020. =)